# Biblatex, verbose-ibid, journal title for repeated citations

Tags: biblatex, journal

I am using Biblatex, and verbose-ibid, and I would like to use author, name of journal for repeated citations of the same article, and author, editor's name and short title of the book for conference proceedings. I want to keep the short title option for books instead.

How can I achieve that? Or is there a style doing that already?

Any help appreciated

For the better explaining: 
I give an example of what I am trying to achieve:

> A. Assmann, "This is an article", *BIFAO* 56 (2000), 23-45.

Later this article should be shortened as

> Assmann, *BIFAO* 56.

For the conference proceedings or contributions to edited books, the original reference should be full:

> R. Parkinson, "This is a contribution", in V. Davies, *This is a book proceedings*, Paris: My publisher, pp. 34-56.

Later it should be shortened to

> Parkinson, in *Book Proceedings*.

The title of the book should be shortened as usual for books.  I give you three examples from my bibliography, but Habachi entry is the "perfect one" (just added):

```
@article{Spalinger.1978b,
 author = {Spalinger, A. J.},
 year = {1978},
 title = {Psammetichus, King of Egypt: II},
 pages = {49–57},
 paginationtype = {page},
 volume = {15},
 journaltitle = {JARCE}
}

@incollection{Hornung.2006,
 author = {Hornung, E. and Krauss, R. and Warburton, David A.},
 title = {Royal Annals},
 pages = {19–25},
 bookpaginationtype = {page},
 subtitle = {Ancient Egyptian Chronology}
}

@incollection{Habachi.1977,
author = {Habachi, Labib},
title = {Mentuhotpe, the Vizier and Son-in-Law of Taharqa},
pages = {165–170},
bookpaginationtype = {page},
publisher = {Akademie-Verlag},
series = {Schriften zur Geschichte und Kultur des Alten Orients},
editor = {Endesfelder, E. and Priese, K.-H and Reineke, W.-F and Wenig, S.},
booktitle = {Ägypten und Kusch},
year = {1977},
usera = {Yes},
shorttitle = {Mentuhotp},
location = {Berlin},
booksubtitle = {Fritz Hintze zum 60. Geburtstag},
number = {13}
```

}

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you may be able to produce this output by renewing the `cite:short` macro in `verbose-ibid.cbx`. You will want to use the `\ifentrytype{article}` and `\ifentrytype{inproceedings}` switches. Could you give a more precise example of what you want to achieve and which bibliography fields you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting this in your preamble seems to work:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
    % If article:
    \ifentrytype{article}{%
        \usebibmacro{journal}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printfield{volume}}{%
    % If incollection:
    \ifentrytype{incollection}{%
        \usebibmacro{in:}%
        \printtext[booktitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}}}{%
    % Else:
    \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}}
```

The `cite:short` macro is called by `verbose-ibid` for references that have already been cited at least once. What I did is redefine it so that it will print the author's name and then, if it is an article, the journal and volume *or* if it is a text in some proceedings, the "in" string and the book title *or* else just the book title.

You may need to add additional entry types (inproceedings, etc.) if you are using them as well. Make sure to comment the end of every line with the `%` character, so as to avoid unwanted spaces.

Comment: The answer above works almost perfectly. For incollection however it add both the main title of the collected work and the subtitle. I am editing the original question, also including another full incollection entry

Comment: I have edited the answer so that it only displays the booktitle field now, which seems to be what you are looking for. — I am also deleting my last paragraph, as I realise this is not an issue in your case (I thought you meant the shorttitle of the main proceedings, which would be quite difficult to implement).

Comment: The solution works perfectly, at least at a first scrutiny. @ienissei, may I contact you again if I need to do some changes about it? Heartfelt thanks

Comment: @RobertoGozzoli Thank you very much for the warm comment. Indeed you can contact me anytime, although some people here are probably more qualified than me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It does not seem to work though when having multiple citations as then it still displays the article title.

Comment: @user1834164 Not sure what you mean, perhaps you should post a new question (with a link to this one), and provide a minimal working example that shows the problem. Please note that my solution only works for entries with types `article` or `incollection`. It might be that there is a problem with one of the tests performed by `verbose-ibid` in order to decide if your reference has already been cited or not. If so, you would have to ask specifically about it. Sorry, I won't be able to look it up for a long time, but if you ask it as a new question, someone else might help.